# Auto generate a csv from Freeform 3.x on server.

Tags: solspace-freeform, csv, automation

how would one be able to get data collected in freeform into a csv on the server. So a CRM can access it via FTP.

Is this even possible? I know very little about cron jobs, is there a plugin that could handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Typically when I've been grabbing a CSV from Freeform data, I've created a template and pulled the entries using the `{exp:freeform:entries}` tag, separating each Freeform field with a comma.

I'd then visit that page and 'Save As' while adding .csv to the file. In terms of automating it, have a look at http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/automatee if writing a cron job isn't your forte.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I am not entriely sure how I would use Automat:ee to automate that. Thanks for the heads up with the {exp:freeform:entries} tag. I forgot to mention, it would need to be automatically downloaded the server every hour.

Comment: Ended up getting a developer to create a custom addon. thanks